# How to create a Form-Specific Help menu in Modern UI?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

One of the standing out features of Acumatica's Modern UI is the **Form-Specific Help** menu, which is opened when you click the Help button while viewing the majority of forms:
[image]

I wonder how big is the effort to create Form-Specific Help menu for a custom screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the [Acumatica ERP documentation](https://help.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=bdabadfb-b464-463d-abe9-502f883aa9a6), to link a reference article with a particular screen, you should specify the Article ID based on the Screen ID of the form, replacing periods with underscores. For example, if the Screen ID is **AP.10.10.00**, the ID of its reference form must be specified as **AP_10_10_00**.

A very similar concept is used to link form-specific help with a particular screen. If you take a quick look at the **Wiki Site Map (SM.20.20.10)**, you should notice the **Form Quick Reference** node under User Guide:
[image]

The **Form Quick Reference** node in its order contains a number of sub-nodes representing different modules of Acumatica ERP. And by checking the list of Wiki articles included into the **Sales Orders** (`User Guide -> Form Quick Reference -> Sales Orders`), you can easily tell, that form-specific help menu is nothing more than a Wiki article linked to a particular screen. To link form-specific help with a particular screen, you should specify the Article ID based on the Screen ID of the form, replacing periods with underscores and adding ***_NAV*** in the end of the Article ID.

[image]

The content of a Wiki article representing form-specific help is usually quite simple:

```
==Procedures==
[HelpRoot_User\SO__How_Create_Sale_Order|To Create a Sales Order (SO)]{br}

...

[HelpRoot_User\SO__How_Process_RM_Order|To Process Authorized Returns (RM)]
==Concepts==
[HelpRoot_User\SO__con_Order_Processing|Sales Order Processing Options]{br}

...

[HelpRoot_User\SO__con_Order_Types_for_Returns|Predefined Order Types for Customer Returns]
==Form Reference==
[HelpRoot_User\SO_30_10_00|Sales Orders] ([~/?ScreenId=SO301000|SO.30.10.00])
==Help Dashboard==
```

For the majority of standard Acumatica ERP screens, form-specific help consists of up to 4 sections:

- Procedures
- Concepts
- Form Reference
- Help Dashboard

Also keep in mind, the Procedures section is considered optional and can be easily excluded from some of form-specific help menus.